# Make two virtual machine on two different computers communicate

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have two VMs running on Windows 2008 guest on two different laptops.

Both laptops can communicate with each other without any problem.

I want to make the two virtual machine communicate. How can I do that?

I'm using VMware.

Both of my VMs have, if starting in the network, 10.104.0.0/24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the VMWare Bridge Networking mode. This integrates them into your local, physical network.